# I am trying to predict the behavior of covid-19 in Colombia, in the Country_Region column, delete all the rows that have countries other than Colombia

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I've been using Pandas' Crop command in Python to remove both rows and columns. I am trying to predict the behavior of covid-19 in Colombia. Now, I need that in the Country_Region column, delete all the rows that have countries other than Colombia, could you help me?

data (.csv): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eEZfBmMQTlJjx1PSmC3bamukqhxR_oAy/view?usp=sharing

[Python1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05GeT.png)
[Python2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUU7s.png)

Comment: At the end of the day you want to have all rows of Colombia - right? By-the-way: Could you make your dataset available for public view?

Comment: Thanks! 
Dataset is available

Comment: Does `columbia_df = df[df['Country_Region'] == 'Columbia']` work? This filters to just the rows where the `Country_Region` column equals "Columbia"

Comment: yes, it's work, thaks. But now doesn't delete the columns that I don't need :(

Comment: You can take the result and write it into a new csv (or database, variable etc.).

Comment: Could you help me? please!

Comment: I'll summarize the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @cookesd : That doesn't work, because you have a typo in your selector ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aim of this question is to separate the data for Country_Region == Colombia.
This gives you the opportunity to go ahead with further evaluations.

1. Step: Read the csv data
2. Step: Apply the selection
3. Step: Take only the result

```
# Do the import
import pandas as pd

# Step 1: Row 0 is defined as the header of the object
df = pd.read_csv('10-01-2020.csv', header=0)

# Apply the selection
df2 = df[df['Country_Region'] == 'Colombia']

# Write the result into a new csv at the same place the script is existing
df2.to_csv('answer.csv')
```

Inside the result answer.csv are only rows of Colombia.

Comment: Result table is in there: https://gist.github.com/squeezer44/307163ccc72d91939d00776055fe2565

Comment: Does that answer your question? If so please mark it by clicking the checkmark. Thx.

Comment: Heyy, I was be able to result the rest of the problem, thank you!!
greetings from Colombia